# How to initialize a @State variable inside a view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that is initialized with a list of items, and then during the initialization process, we need to pick one item at random. Something like this:

```
struct ItemsView: View {

    var items:[Item]
    @State var current:Item?

    init(items:[Item] = []) {
        self.items = items
        if items.count > 0 {
            let index = Int.random(in: 0..<items.count)
            self.current = items[index] // doesnt work
        }
        if current != nil {
            print("init with", self.items.count, "items. Chose", current!)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The job of the `ItemsVew` is to show one item at time, at random, so we start by picking an item at random, but `self.current = items[index]` literally doesn't do anything as far as I can tell, for reasons I don't understand. So either I am doing something silly, or I am thinking about how to solve this in an incorrectly somehow.

So how do you initialize a State variable in the init function. I have tried:

```
self.current = State(initialValue: items[index])
```

But that simply triggers a compiler error. So how do we select an initial item that will be used when the view is displayed?

```
Cannot assign value of type 'State<Item>' to type 'Item'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `@State` is a property wrapper, you want to assign to the underlying variable itself, not the wrapped value type (which is `Item?` in this case).

```swift
self._current = State(initialValue: items[index])
//   ^ note the underscore
```

The best documentation for this is available in the original [Swift Evolution SE-0258](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md) proposal document.

Answer (score 0):

`@State` is a [property wrapper](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html), so you will need to assign a `Item?` object to the `current` property that is why the compiler gives you an error. So as long as the items array you pass is not empty, this should work as expected. Also I encourage you to use `randomElement()` method on the `items` array instead of producing a random index.

```swift
struct ItemsView: View {

    var items: [Item]
    @State var current: Item?

    init(items: [Item] = []) {
        self.items = items
        self.current = items.randomElement()
        if let item = current {
            print("init with", self.items.count, "items. Choose", item)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This won't actually work because SwiftUI doesn't allow you to change the value of a state property in the initialiser.  You have to initialise the underlying state property itself i.e. self._current.

Comment: How is that? I just just checked and I was able to assign a value to @State property in an init without any errors

Comment: Yep it doesn't give an error but also doesn't set the value.  You should find that the State property is still the default you had for it.